# possible values of $email_from

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I am getting an error when I click the submit button on the form (error; you need to submit the form). I'm not sure how but I think it's because of the value of the $email_form. Am I doing it wrong? Should I change the value of my $email_form. Are there any other problems?

```html
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
 echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$phoneno = $_POST['phoneno'];
$datefrom = $_POST['datefrom'];
$dateto = $_POST['dateto'];
$emailto = $_POST['emailto'];

//Validate first
if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)) 
{
    echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
    exit;
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

$email_from = "$visitor_email";//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "Leave Application";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n\n".
    "Here is the message:\n\nLeave Date - From: $datefrom To: $dateto \n\n".
 "Phone Number: $phoneno\n\n".
 "$message \n\n".
    
$to = $_POST['emailTo'];//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: leavesuccess.php');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}
   
?>
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="form__name" style="font-family: Questrial; ">
            Apply for a leave 
        </div>
        <div class="time__container">
            <div class="section">
                <div class="box">
                    1
                </div><span>Date &amp; Time</span>
            </div>
            <form action="form-to-email.php" class="form__time" method="post">
                <div class="date">
                    <label for="date">From</label> <input id="date" type="date" name="datefrom">
                </div>
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
                <div class="date">
                    <label for="date">To</label> <input id="date" type="date" name="dateto">
                </div>
                <div class="timezone">
                    <label for="timezone"></label> 
                        </select>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="message__container">
            <div class="section">
                <div class="box">
     2
                  
                </div><span>Message</span>
            </div>
            <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="contact__container">
            <div class="section">
                <div class="box">
     3
                    
                </div><span>Contact Information</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form__contact">
                <div class="cname">
                    <label for="cname">Name</label> <input name="name" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="cnum">
                    <label for="cnum">Phone Number</label> <input id="cnum" type="text" name="phoneno">
                </div>
                <div class="email">
                    <label for="cemail">Email</label> <input id="cemail" name="email">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  <div class="contact__container">
            <div class="section">
                <div class="box">
     4
                    
                </div><span>Send to</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form__contact">
                <div class="cname">
                    <label for="cname">Manager</label> <select name="emailTo">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="email@email.com">TestingRenzo</option>
     <option value="email@email.com">TestingPaul</option>
     <option value="email@email.com">Lenz Batara</option>
     <option value="email@email.com">Patrick Laqui</option>
     <option value="email@email.com">Joseph Enierga</option>
     <option value="email@email.com">Gino Ilustre</option>
     <option value="email@email.com">Marissa Guirwela</option>
     <option value="email@email.com">Angeli Jocson</option>
     </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form__confirmation" type="submit" name="submit">
            <button>Confirm Information</button>
        </div>
  </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Removed the emails for privacy

Comment: post the HTML (form) for this.

Comment: You also have `$_POST['emailto']` and `$_POST['emailTo']` being two different animals here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I still get the error :(